# Raspberry Pi's local hostname doesn't work on Android phones

Tags: web-server, android

I am trying to access `raspberrypi.local` from my android device. I have set up avahi daemon on the rpi and can access the web server from my PC but it's not working for any of the android devices.

What could I be doing wrong?

Comment: This question belongs to android and not to Raspberry Pi.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your situation is explained on [Android SE](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/49188/how-to-get-mdns-working-for-chrome-on-android). Android doesn't include mDNS in standard name resolution results, so unless the Android app you're using explicitly uses mDNS library, it will not see `raspberrypi.local`.

Your options are to either find (or write) an Android app with mDNS support, or set up a regular DNS server in your network. Your router may already have such a feature.

Answer (score 4):

You're out of luck. Android doesn't have any support for Bonjour (aka mDNS, aka zeroconf networking). You'll need to discover your Raspberry Pi's IP address (192.168.xxx.xxx) and use that.

It's available on Windows (if you have Apple's iTunes or Bonjour installed), it's available on Linux with avahi-daemon and the avahi-tools and because Apple invented it, it's available on OSX, ipads and iphones.

Comment: I really don't see how Bonjour (an Apple software) is related to the connection between a Pi and an Android phone.

Comment: Bonjour was the first (widely used and actually usable) zeroconf networking implementation - Avahi is linux implementation - I think windows 10 has something too (so no need to install Bonjour anymore) - odd that Android, which is linux based, doesn't

Comment: `Android doesn't have any support for Bonjour` not strictly true - https://developer.android.com/training/connect-devices-wirelessly/nsd - of course, that doesn't help a browser (chrome/firefox etc) on Android

Comment: You wrote: "*It's available on Windows (if you have Apple's iTunes or Bonjour installed)*". Do you know where to get/download **Bonjour for MS Windows**?

Comment: https://support.apple.com/downloads/bonjour_for_windows you get it for free if you have iTunes (which I don't have).